# How can I tilt a rotating plane?

Tags: c, opengl, graphic

I am writing a simulation of solar system using OpenGL in C.
There's a body array which stores all the planets information.
I want the planet orbit to tilt a certain angle, however from the result, the planet and the orbit are rotating around the (0,0,0) all the time. How could i fix that?
Here's some of my code.

Here's the definition of the array 'bodies'

```
typedef struct {
    char    name[20];       /* name */
    GLfloat r, g, b;        /* colour */
    GLfloat orbital_radius; /* distance to parent body (km) */
    GLfloat orbital_tilt;   /* angle of orbit wrt ecliptic (deg) */
    GLfloat orbital_period; /* time taken to orbit (days) */
    GLfloat radius;         /* radius of body (km) */
    GLfloat axis_tilt;      /* tilt of axis wrt body's orbital plane (deg) */
    GLfloat rot_period;     /* body's period of rotation (days) */
    GLint   orbits_body;    /* identifier of parent body */
    GLfloat spin;           /* current spin value (deg) */
    GLfloat orbit;          /* current orbit value (deg) */
} body;
```

The following is the function to draw exactly the planet. It needs to tilt around its axis to rotate, and the orbit needs to tilt as well.

```
void drawBody(int n)
{
    glRotatef(bodies[n].orbital_tilt,0,0,1); //toilet
    drawOrbit(n);
    glRotatef(bodies[n].orbit,0,1,0);//orb
    glTranslatef(bodies[n].orbital_radius,0,0); 
    // self axis tilt
    glRotatef(bodies[n].axis_tilt,0,0,1);//atilt

    /* rotate on its own */
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(bodies[n].spin,0,1,0); //self-spin
        glRotatef(90,1,0,0); //vert
        glColor3f(bodies[n].r,bodies[n].g,bodies[n].b);
        glLineWidth(1.0);
        glutWireSphere(bodies[n].radius,15,15);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

and my draw orbit function:

```
void drawOrbit (int n)
{ /* Draws a polygon to approximate the circular
   orbit of body "n" */
    float angle = 2*PI/ORBIT_POLY_SIDES;
    float r = bodies[n].orbital_radius;
    float i ;

    glPushMatrix();
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(bodies[n].r,bodies[n].g,bodies[n].b);
        for (i = 0; i < 2*PI; i+=angle){
            glVertex3f(r*sin(i),0,r*cos(i));
        }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    /* This is for you to complete. */
}
```